# Need assistance copying task

Tags: powershell

I have .dll and .sys files under folder xyz
   xyz
      'QcXhciFilter8086\QcXhciFilter8086.sys'
      'qSarMgr8086\qSarMgr.dll'
      'qcwlan_wpextwapi8086\WapiIhvExt.dll'

These need to be copied something like this under new folder
   new
      'QcXhciFilter8086\QcXhciFilter8086.sys'
      'qSarMgr8086\qSarMgr.dll'
      'qcwlan_wpextwapi8086\WapiIhvExt.dll'

What i have tried:

```
'Copy-Item -Path $file_path\..\*sys -Destination C:\Users\Path\new\'
```

Here '$file_path = \xyz\QcXhciFilter8086\QcXhciFilter8086.sys'

Result: Only .sys.dll files getting copied directly under "new" folder. However i want them under the driver name. Something like this 'new\QcXhciFilter8086\QcXhciFilter8086.sys'

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues are you getting? SO won't provide fully functioning scripts for you :)

Comment: I have tried this --> Copy-item -Path $file_path\..\..\*sys -Destination C:\Users\c_ahanma\Desktop\reproo\new\  and only files ending with .sys are getting copied to "new " folder. However i want them inside driver name. Something like this new\qdcmlib8680\qdcmlib.Win32.dll

Comment: I have updated your question for you but it would be good practice for your to update your question in future. Please make sure that your question has all the relevant information

Comment: Does the updated question make my doubt more clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you are asking for...

You have a folder structure like this:

[xyz]

- QcXhciFilter8086

  - QcXhciFilter8086.sys
- qSarMgr8086

  - qSarMgr.dll
- qcwlan_wpextwapi8086

  - WapiIhvExt.dll

And you want this copying to another folder. Using this will copy the folder structure and files from the xyz folder to the new folder. This will copy everything, however. If you only want to copy the files that are only .sys and .dll then you will need to add another `Get-ChildItem` in the existing `ForeEach-Object` loop to look at the current directory.

Here is my proposed solution:

```
$source = "c:\path\to\xyz"
$destination = "c:\path\to\new"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destination -Recurse -Container
}
```

Comment: Sir you made my day. I was missing " -Recurse -Container". Thanks a lottttttttt.